# RewriteCond n RewriteRule make me crazy

Tags: .htaccess

I've got a .htaccess file with this cond n rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(somedir/|$)(/.*)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://other.domain.com/$0 [L,QSA]
```

I need to redirect all request from first site to another with request_uri not containing "somedir" in the beginning and I need MORE to not redirect if my request_uri's empty or /

Sorry 4 my eng. Thanx 4 any help.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(somedir(/.*|)|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://other.domain.com/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: first - lego.detishop.ru
second - online.detishop.ru

Comment: Isn't that expected since you wanted this behavior `I need MORE to not redirect if my request_uri's empty or /` Now for your URL: `lego.detishop.ru second` `REQUEST_URI` will be `/` and skip the rule because of RewriteCond